# Bind array param to native query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have table **product_spec_entry** with following columns:

- product_spec_id
- commodity_spec_id

for one **product_spec_id** may be several **commodity_spec_id**, for example:

```
|product_spec_id | commodity_spec_id|
|----------------|------------------|
|1683            |1681              |
|1692            |1693              |
|1692            |1681              |
|1692            |1687              |
|1692            |1864              |
|1860            |1681              |
|1868            |1681              |
|1868            |1864              |
```

I want get all **product_spec_id** that have all **commodity_spec_id** are passed as parameter.

I wrote next query:

```
SELECT ps.product_spec_id, commodities
FROM (
       SELECT
         product_spec_id,
         array_agg(commodity_spec_id) AS commodities
       FROM system.product_spec_entry
       GROUP BY product_spec_id) ps
WHERE Cast(ARRAY [1681, 1864] as BIGINT[]) <@ Cast(ps.commodities as BIGINT[]);
```

It's work fine, and return expected result:

> product_spec_id = 1692, 1868

I try use this query for JPA native query:

```
String query = "SELECT ps.product_spec_id " +
                "FROM ( " +
                "       SELECT " +
                "         product_spec_id, " +
                "         array_agg(commodity_spec_id) AS commodities " +
                "       FROM system.product_spec_entry " +
                "       GROUP BY product_spec_id) ps " +
                "WHERE CAST(ARRAY[:commoditySpecIds] AS BIGINT[]) <@ CAST(ps.commodities AS BIGINT[])";
List<Long> commoditySpecsIds = commoditySpecs.stream().map(Spec::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<BigInteger> productSpecIds = em.createNativeQuery(query).setParameter("commoditySpecIds", commoditySpecsIds)
                .getResultList();
```

It does not work because I get array of record (`ARRAY[(1692, 1868)]`) instead array of bigint (`ARRAY[1692, 1868]`)

How I should bind array param to my query? May be I can use more simple query for it.

Comment: In plain JDBC you can pass an array through `PreparedStatement.setArray()` but I don't know if your obfuscation layer allows that

Comment: I can not use JDBC, I can create query only with **EntityManager**

Comment: Isn't there a `setArray()` equivalent in your obfuscation layer?

Answer (score 12):

Leave out the `array[...]` from your SQL:

```
WHERE CAST(:commoditySpecIds AS BIGINT[])
```

and then pass the list of IDs as a string that looks like this:

```
"{1,2,3,4}"
```

The default toString() for Lists usually returns something like: `"[1,2,3]"`, so you could do something like this:

```
String literal = commoditySpecsIds.toString();
literal = "{" + literal.substring(1,literal.length() - 1) + "};
```

and then pass that to your obfuscation layer:

```
setParameter("commoditySpecIds", literal)
```

Comment: It threw **PersistenceException**, because syntax error on CAST **({** 1,2,3,4})

Comment: @HAYMbl4 Then try to add single quotes to the literal: `literal = "'{" + literal.substring(1,literal.length() - 1) + "}'";`

Comment: It's work from console but not from java.. (org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement) and nothing more info.. it's work with following construction `CAST(string_to_array(:params, ',') AS BIGINT [])` where :commoditySPecIds = "1,2,3,4". But it's "hot fix".. if I found normal fix way I write it here

Comment: Why did you add that `string_to_array()`? This is not what I put in my answer. It's not needed if you use the literal I have show and the cast.

Comment: I alrady wrote why.. beacase it's work only when I call query from console but not work when I use it in java code..

Answer (score 8):

I'm exactly in the same situation. Hope @VladMihalcea can help us

Edit

I figure it out to do it with JPA. After reading the impementation of setParameter, i discovered something similar to UserType, the TypedParameterValue.

When you use

```
setParameter("commoditySpecIds", new TypedParameterValue(IntArrayType.INSTANCE, commoditySpecsIds))
```

Where IntArrayType.INSTANCE come from "hibernate-types" librairy provided by Vlad Mihalcea. Be carefull, the "commoditySpecsIds" must be an array, not a Collection.

Hope that helps

Comment: Perfect - spent a couple of hours before I found this - works perfectly! https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Other approcah for your case is unwrap the JPA provider session and use some methods form the JPA provider API.

If you are using hibernate, you can do the follow:

```
// unwrap hibenate session
final Session hibernateSession = em.unwrap(Session.class);

// create you SQL query in hibernate style
final SQLQuery sqlQuery = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery(sql);
```

And then set the parameter also using hibernate API

```
final Type customType = new CustomType(new ArrayTypeUser());
sqlQuery.setParameter("commoditySpecIds", value, customType);
```

Where "ArrayTypeUser" is a custom type that maps PostgresSQL array type to a Java array type.

This is not the best solution, but as you is  are already using native queries, maybe for this particular case the best solution is skip the JPA standard API and use the JPA provide API.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is very simple - you should be using Array instead of List here.

```
final var commoditySpecs = List.of(new Spec(1681), new Spec(1864));
final Long[] commoditySpecsIds = commoditySpecs.stream().map(Spec::getId).toArray(Long[]::new);
final List<Integer> resultList = entityManager
        .createNativeQuery("""
                           SELECT ps.product_spec_id
                           FROM (
                                    SELECT
                                        product_spec_id,
                                        array_agg(commodity_spec_id) AS commodities
                                    FROM product_spec_entry
                                    GROUP BY product_spec_id) ps
                           WHERE Cast(:commoditySpecIds as BIGINT[]) <@ Cast(ps.commodities as BIGINT[]);
                           """)
        .setParameter("commoditySpecIds", commoditySpecsIds)
        .getResultList();
for (final var o : resultList) {
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

prints

```
1692
1868
```