# JPA nativeQuery taking a list/set/array as parameter

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

Using a postgres database, I have the following entity : table `cards.combo` and column `colors VARCHAR[]`, example of values `{'red', 'blue'}`

I want to find the Combos that have no colors in common, using the overlap operator (&&)

I can't find out how to formulate the correct nativeQuery, something similar to this :

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM cards.combo cc WHERE cc.colors && CAST(ARRAY[(:providedColors)] AS VARCHAR[])")
List<Combo> findOverlaps(@Param("providedColors") List<String> providedColors);
```

In a console, this test works fine :

```
SELECT * FROM cards.combo cc WHERE cc.colors && CAST(ARRAY['red'] AS VARCHAR[])
```

The syntax `(:param)` is supposedly correct with other primitive parameters (int, string). I struggle to get the param `providedColors` converted to an array[] in the query.

Thanks !

---

edit : found a workaround :provide colors as a csv string, and use `&& CAST(STRING_TO_ARRAY((:providedColors),',') AS VARCHAR[])`

Comment: Have you try with the curly braces syntax (SELECT * FROM cards.combo cc WHERE cc.colors && '{"blue", "red"}' ) ? For that you will need to parse providedColors to String instead

Comment: Did you look here?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020972/bind-array-param-to-native-query.

Comment: Just curious - how does the :providecolors as a csv string look like?

Answer (score -4):

```
public interface EmployeeDAO extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
    List<Employee> findByEmployeeNameIn(List<String> names);                
    // 1. Spring JPA In cause using method name
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.employeeName IN (:names)")     
    // 2. Spring JPA In cause using @Query
    List<Employee> findByEmployeeNames(@Param("names")List<String> names);
    @Query(nativeQuery =true,value = "SELECT * FROM Employee as e WHERE e.employeeName IN (:names)")   // 3. Spring JPA In cause using native query
    List<Employee> findByEmployeeName(@Param("names") List<String> names);
}
```