# How to use query operators && or @> when creating a native query in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(
    postid SERIAL NOT NULL,
    owner SERIAL NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    continent VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    languages VARCHAR(100)[] NOT NULL,
    properties varchar(100) ARRAY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (postid),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(userid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

```java
final Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE :properties <@ properties");
query.setParameter("properties", propAux);
```

I'm migrating my project to hibernate (I'm using the version 1.0.0.Final of javax.persistence.Query), and I can't seem to run that query. It says that `<@` operator doesn't work with types `bytea` and suggests to cast it. I tried casting it to `text[]`, replacing `:properties <@ properties` with `cast(:properties as text[]) <@ cast(properities as text[])` but didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

PS: `propAux` is an array of Strings.

Comment: What type is the column "properties"?

Comment: The type is varchar(100)[]

Comment: Surely the error message changed when you added the cast?  Please copy and paste the exact error message

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to text[]
  Position: 44

Comment: Maybe one of the answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020972/bind-array-param-to-native-query) would help? 

Options discussed there are passing in a string like `"{'a','b','c'}"` and casting to array, or using  ```setParameter("properties", new TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE, propAux))
```

You could use something like `select pg_typeof(:properties)` to see what's bound in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following setup:

```sql
create table TST_POSTS
(
   postid int,
   properties varchar(200)[],
   
   primary key (postid)
);

insert into TST_POSTS
values (1, '{"aaa", "bbb"}'), (2, '{"aaa", "ccc"}'), (4, '{"ddd", "ccc"}');
```

You can write the following query:

```java
import org.hibernate.jpa.TypedParameterValue;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType;

// ...

List<Integer> results = entityManager
   .createNativeQuery("select postid from TST_POSTS where :prop <@ cast(properties as text[])")
   .setParameter("prop", new TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE, new String[] {"ccc"}))
   .getResultList();
```

and you will get the output:

```
2
4
```

This approach requires to have [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) as a dependency.

P.S. I tested it with `hibernate-types-52` (version 2.10.1) and hibernate 5.4.29.Final. See also [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/bind-custom-hibernate-parameter-type-jpa-query/).

**EDIT**

You can use the following query for hibernate 5.1.0.Final:

```java
import org.hibernate.Query;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType;

// ...

Query query = entityManager
   .createNativeQuery("select postid from TEST_SCHEMA.TST_POSTS where :prop <@ cast(properties as text[])")
   .unwrap(Query.class)
   .setParameter("prop", new String[] {"ccc"}, StringArrayType.INSTANCE);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer> result = query.list();
```

and you should use the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of `hibernate-types-52`.

Comment: Yes, I have a similar setup. I'll edit the post and add it so you can see.
I did what you suggested here. But still for some reason it reads my varchar(100)[] from the db as bytea and I get this error: 

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to text[]
  Position: 44

The problem is obviously coming from the cast(properties as text[]). I also don't have that version of hibernate. I have version 5.1.0.Final.

Comment: 1. Why you use 5.1.0.Final instead of the latest version from 5.4 branch? 2. What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Apparently I tried doing away with cast() and still got the same error. So maybe the error does come from casting it in the TypedParameterValue function?

Comment: I use 5.1.0.Final because other things depend on it and can't change it because they all break.

Comment: Even if I do away with TypedParameterValue() it still gives me the same error. I honestly don't know what to do anymore haha

Comment: The hibernate dialect I am using is: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect"

Comment: MY BAD Apparently I have the version 5.1.4.FINAL I forgot I had changed it. I'm sorry man

Comment: Basically for version 5.1.4.FINAL I can't use the fucntion setParameter(String, String[], StringArrayType.INSTANCE) (It doesn't exist)

Comment: I also set the function unwrap(Query.class) but it did nothing so far.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have double checked my version

Comment: It is not important, the above solution for `5.1.0.Final` should work for the `5.1.4.Final` version too.

Comment: Mmhh doesn't work for me. It says"the method setParameter(Str, Clanedar, TemporalType) in the query is not applicable for the argumetns (Str, Str[],..)

Comment: my org.hibernate.jpa.version is 1.0.0.Final
My org.hibernate.version is 5.1.4.Final

Comment: <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.hibernate.jpa.version}</version>
            </dependency>

I notice that I'm using javax.persistence for the type Query.

Comment: yes, that's definitely the issue here. I'm using javax.persistence.Query instead of org.hibernate.Query; I can't replace it because I've worked with javax.persistence all the time. Could there be a solution to this using javax.persistence.Query?