# How to change brackets for postgresql?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, postgresql

I want to retrieve data from this query. But this query works if col has only one value. If there is 2 or more value it doesn't work.

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM art where color @> ARRAY[:col]",
            nativeQuery=true)
    List<Recept> findBy( @Param("col") Set<Integer> col);
```

By hibernate I see the query. this one works fine.

```
Hibernate: SELECT *   FROM  art  where color @> ARRAY[(?)]
```

While this doesn't work. **ERROR: operator does not exist**: integer[] @> record[]

```
Hibernate: SELECT *   FROM  art  where color @> ARRAY[(?, ?)]
```

I think the problem is in brackets.

Comment: I've never written a query like this before in PostGres, but if you look carefully at the error message, it thinks `ARRAY[(?, ?)]` is a `record[]`

Comment: yeah noticed it too but dont know why it is this way

Comment: Probably because it didn't expect you to hand it a `record[]`.

Comment: Think carefully about what the error message is saying.

Comment: idk why it is presented as a record since I pass set integer

Comment: No, you passed it a set of `integer, integer`.

Comment: Or you passed it a two dimensional array index.  Either way, it surely doesn't match `ARRAY[(?)]`

Comment: no i didn't use two-dimensional array neither postgres or entity

Comment: Well, you're going to have to figure it out.  Clearly PostGres is expecting something of the form `ARRAY[(?)]`, not `ARRAY[(?, ?)]`

Comment: color data type is integer[] . I checked in pgAdmin Array[1,2] works fine with the same query

Comment: Then you're leaving something out of your question that we need to see.  Aren't those question marks parameters?  How are you populating them?

Comment: I would like to see it like this SelECT *   FROM  art  where color @> ARRAY[?, ?]

Comment: You want `array[?,?]` - the expression `(?,?)` is a single value which is an anonymous record type (with two fields)

Comment: well I checked in pgadmin SelECT * FROM art where color @> ARRAY[1, 2] it works fine while in the repository  SelECT * FROM art where color @> ARRAY[(1, 2)] it gives error

Comment: As  I wrote: `ARRAY[(1, 2)]` is something completely different than `ARRAY[1, 2]`. The first expression is an array with a single element, the second is an array with two integer. Just get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: thats smth Idk how

Answer (score 1):

You may change the code to this

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM art where color in :col",
            nativeQuery=true)
    List<Recept> findBy( @Param("col") Set<Integer> col);
```

So the resultant query will be

```
SELECT *   FROM  art  where color in (1,2,3)
```

Where (1,2,3) is a [list of scalar values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) used along with the `IN` operator

TD;DR:

Your problem is that you are passing as second argument to the `@>` operator a list of rows and not a list of integers. As horse_with_no_name states in the comments, you are generating a wrong query trying to compare things of different nature.

Comment: it didn't work ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer. Also I need a list of rows since I want to get art with colors red AND yellow(that's why color column is int[]).

Comment: @FireHe4d look this is exacly a another question of another persona that faces the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020972/bind-array-param-to-native-query, so probably you will have a **common accepted answer** for both problems. Also consider to dig further into docs like https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-arrays-with-hibernate/#Map_it_as_a_Native_Database_Array AND https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: another folk facing the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232828/how-to-using-like-array-of-string-hibernate